# Equivalent measures and independence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Suppose that $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are two equivalent measures in a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr F)$. Suppose that random variables $\xi_1,..,\xi_n$ in $(\Omega, \mathscr F)$ are independent according to $\mu$, does this imply that they are independent also according to $\lambda$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, let $\xi_1,\xi_2$ uniformly distributed on the unit square i.e. $\xi_1,\xi_2$ are random variables on $(\Omega, \mathscr F) = ([0,1] \times [0,1], \mathscr F)$. So they are independent with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Now, take the following common density instead

$$f_{\xi_1,\xi_2}(x,y)=x+y, \,\,\, 0\le x\le 1, 0\le y\le 1.\tag 1$$

With respect to this common distribution the two random variables are not independent.

$$f_{\xi_1}(x)=x+\frac12,\,\,0\le x \le 1$$
and

$$f_{\xi_2}(y)=y+\frac12,\,\,0\le y \le 1.$$

So,
$$f_{\xi_1,\xi_2}(x,y)\not=f_{\xi_1}(x)f_{\xi_2}(y).$$

At the same time the two measures (the Lebesgue measure and the one defined by $(1)$) are [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_(measure_theory)). They are absolute continuous with respect to each other.

Comment: Suppose then that, under $\mathbb{P}$ the random variables are independent and identically distributed with $\mathbb{P}\left[\xi_t=a\right]=p$ and $\mathbb{P}\left[\xi_t=b\right]=1-p$.    I am wondering whether (and for which conditions)  independence is preserved by any new measure such that $\mathbb{Q}\left[\xi_t=a\right]=p^{\prime}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\left[\xi_t=b\right]=1-p^{\prime}$.

Comment: What exactly are the $\lambda$ and $\mu$ here?

Comment: @BCLC: $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\mu$ is the measure defined by the density $x+y$ over the unit square.

Comment: @zoli So $$\mu(E) = \int\int_{E} \ x+y \ dA$$ for $E \in \mathscr{F}$ where $E \subseteq [0,1] \times [0,1] = \Omega$?

Comment: @DP1981 $\mu = \mathbb P, \lambda = \mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: @zoli Nice. So what do you call the '[natural](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511031/why-do-we-consider-borel-sets-instead-of-measurable-sets/1511273)' $\mathscr F$ here? $\mathscr{B}(\Omega)$ ? Not familiar w/ multivariate prob/measure theory

Comment: @DP1981: yes. $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb Q$ are the two distributions.